# Chrome Developer Tools, goto what originated of the 404 error being displayed in console

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome dev tools, when the line for 404 error is displayed, is there any way to find the origin of what caused the error?

I have tried right clicking on it, double clicking it, etc. but besides seeing that 404 error was caused somewhere in the page or loaded javascripts etc. I can't see what caused the request to be issued.

Update:
all I see is a line :

GET http://localhost:58780/manifest.json 404 (Not Found)  | manifest.json

hovering over "manifest.json" all it shows is "http://localhost:58780/manifest.json"

trying to find out what or how when the request was issued.

Comment: When you hover your mouse over the underlined source file that being reported error, you will see the root of specific source file that caused the error ( `404 Not Found`, `Value undefined` etc.) In most cases, it could be any other issue that would causes the error rather than `.js` file etc. Since your issue here is obscure, you will have to look into the error log and evaluate it.

Comment: @si_the_nibba : tried that, updated my question, still cant find out any of the what, where,when caused the get request to be issued